# How to recursively find the connections using dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

- I have the below dataframe.

```
data = {
    'Row_Id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'Inbound_Connection': [[2, 5, 3], [3], [4], [1], [], [3], [4]],
    'Outbound_Connection': [[4], [1], [1, 6, 2], [3, 7], [1], [], []],
    'Row_Text': ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4', 'Row 5', 'Row 6', 'Row 7']
}
```

```
| Row_Id | Inbound_Connection | Outbound_Connection | Row_Text |
| ------ | ------------------ | ------------------- | -------- |
| 1      | [2, 5, 3]          | [4]                 | Row 1    |
| 2      | [3]                | [1]                 | Row 2    |
| 3      | [4]                | [1, 6, 2]           | Row 3    |
| 4      | [1]                | [3, 7]              | Row 4    |
| 5      | []                 | [1]                 | Row 5    |
| 6      | [3]                | []                  | Row 6    |
| 7      | [4]                | []                  | Row 7    |
```

- What I am trying to achieve is given a row, I want to retrieve first it's `Inbound_Connection` and `Outbound_Connection`. Further identify the `Inbound_Connection` and `Outbound_Connection` for the identified connections in the previous step in recursive manner.
- What I have achieved is, I am able to retrieve the output in recursive manner. But when the `Inbound_Connection` and `Outbound_Connection` column both contains more than 1 elements in the list I am not getting the output for the `Outbound_Connection`. Or either I am not able to retrieve the `Inbound_Connection` and the `Outbound_Connection` for the nested ones.
- Code

```
import pandas 

data = {
    'Row_Id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'Inbound_Connection': [[2, 5, 3], [3], [4], [1], [], [3], [4]],
    'Outbound_Connection': [[4], [1], [1, 6, 2], [3, 7], [1], [], []],
    'Row_Text': ['Row 1', 'Row 2', 'Row 3', 'Row 4', 'Row 5', 'Row 6', 'Row 7']
}
df = pandas.DataFrame(data)


def find_connections(df, row_id, visited=None):
    if visited is None:
        visited = set()
    if row_id in visited:
        return {}

    visited.add(row_id)
    row = df[df['Row_Id'] == row_id]

    if row.empty:
        return {}

    row_text = row['Row_Text'].values[0]
    inbound_connections = row['Inbound_Connection'].values[0]
    outbound_connections = row['Outbound_Connection'].values[0]

    connections_dict = {'Row_Text': row_text}
    if inbound_connections:
        connections_dict['Inbound'] = {}
        for connection in inbound_connections:
            connections_dict['Inbound'][connection] = find_connections(df, connection, visited)

    if outbound_connections:
        connections_dict['Outbound'] = {}
        for connection in outbound_connections:
            connections_dict['Outbound'][connection] = find_connections(df, connection, visited)

    return connections_dict


connections_dict = {}
for row_id in df['Row_Id']:
    connections_dict[row_id] = find_connections(df, row_id)

print(connections_dict)
```

- Output

```
{1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1', 'Inbound': {2: {'Row_Text': 'Row 2', 'Inbound': {3: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3', 'Inbound': {4: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4', 'Inbound': {1: {}}, 'Outbound': {3: {}, 7: {'Row_Text': 'Row 7', 'Inbound': {4: {}}}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}, 6: {'Row_Text': 'Row 6', 'Inbound': {3: {}}}, 2: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 5: {'Row_Text': 'Row 5', 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 3: {}}, 'Outbound': {4: {}}}, 2: {'Row_Text': 'Row 2', 'Inbound': {3: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3', 'Inbound': {4: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4', 'Inbound': {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1', 'Inbound': {2: {}, 5: {'Row_Text': 'Row 5', 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 3: {}}, 'Outbound': {4: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {3: {}, 7: {'Row_Text': 'Row 7', 'Inbound': {4: {}}}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}, 6: {'Row_Text': 'Row 6', 'Inbound': {3: {}}}, 2: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 3: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3', 'Inbound': {4: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4', 'Inbound': {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1', 'Inbound': {2: {'Row_Text': 'Row 2', 'Inbound': {3: {}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 5: {'Row_Text': 'Row 5', 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 3: {}}, 'Outbound': {4: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {3: {}, 7: {'Row_Text': 'Row 7', 'Inbound': {4: {}}}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}, 6: {'Row_Text': 'Row 6', 'Inbound': {3: {}}}, 2: {}}}, 4: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4', 'Inbound': {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1', 'Inbound': {2: {'Row_Text': 'Row 2', 'Inbound': {3: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3', 'Inbound': {4: {}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}, 6: {'Row_Text': 'Row 6', 'Inbound': {3: {}}}, 2: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 5: {'Row_Text': 'Row 5', 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 3: {}}, 'Outbound': {4: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {3: {}, 7: {'Row_Text': 'Row 7', 'Inbound': {4: {}}}}}, 5: {'Row_Text': 'Row 5', 'Outbound': {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1', 'Inbound': {2: {'Row_Text': 'Row 2', 'Inbound': {3: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3', 'Inbound': {4: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4', 'Inbound': {1: {}}, 'Outbound': {3: {}, 7: {'Row_Text': 'Row 7', 'Inbound': {4: {}}}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}, 6: {'Row_Text': 'Row 6', 'Inbound': {3: {}}}, 2: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 5: {}, 3: {}}, 'Outbound': {4: {}}}}}, 6: {'Row_Text': 'Row 6', 'Inbound': {3: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3', 'Inbound': {4: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4', 'Inbound': {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1', 'Inbound': {2: {'Row_Text': 'Row 2', 'Inbound': {3: {}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 5: {'Row_Text': 'Row 5', 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 3: {}}, 'Outbound': {4: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {3: {}, 7: {'Row_Text': 'Row 7', 'Inbound': {4: {}}}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}, 6: {}, 2: {}}}}}, 7: {'Row_Text': 'Row 7', 'Inbound': {4: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4', 'Inbound': {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1', 'Inbound': {2: {'Row_Text': 'Row 2', 'Inbound': {3: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3', 'Inbound': {4: {}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}, 6: {'Row_Text': 'Row 6', 'Inbound': {3: {}}}, 2: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 5: {'Row_Text': 'Row 5', 'Outbound': {1: {}}}, 3: {}}, 'Outbound': {4: {}}}}, 'Outbound': {3: {}, 7: {}}}}}}
```

Comment: `Row 2` has multiple outbound connections but it does show multiple rows in its `Outbound_Connection` in its output from what I see. I think it's because you keep track of the visited row in `visited` set so when the row is traversed in a depth-first-search pattern for inbound connection, all the visited rows won't get traversed further in outbound connection

Comment: I tried removing that visited check, but it reached the max-depth in recursion. Is there any other data structure which I can implement to avoid it?

Comment: To avoid the above issue, you could keep track of 2 separate visited sets, one for outbound, one for inbound instead. What is your expected output given the above input?

Comment: Given a row, I want to find its inbound and outbound connections for every individual row. Basically, it will be used to identify the causes and effects for every individual row.

Answer (score 0):

The exact logic is not fully clear, but this looks like a graph problem. You can [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) you input and pass it to [`networkx`](https://networkx.org) to automatically build a nested output dictionary with [`to_dict_of_dicts`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_dict_of_dicts.html):

```
tmp = df.explode('Inbound_Connection').explode('Outbound_Connection')

G1 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tmp.dropna(), create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                             source='Inbound_Connection', target='Row_Id',
                             edge_attr='Row_Text'
                            )
G2 = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(tmp.dropna(), create_using=nx.DiGraph,
                             source='Row_Id', target='Outbound_Connection',
                             edge_attr='Row_Text'
                            )

G = nx.compose(G1, G2)

out = nx.to_dict_of_dicts(G)
```

Output:

```
{2: {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 2'}},
 1: {4: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1'}},
 5: {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 1'}},
 3: {1: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3'},
  2: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3'},
  6: {'Row_Text': 'Row 3'}},
 4: {3: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4'}, 7: {'Row_Text': 'Row 4'}},
 6: {},
 7: {}}
```

Graph:

[image]

Comment: For 2, it didn't find inbound of 3. It found outbound as 1 only? I want to be able to find the Inbound and Outbound first correctly and then I thing with the help of the above code I should be able to find its child.